# retrieve image from gallery in android

Tags: android

I have created an `Activity` where i have a `Button`.

By pressing the button an android `Gallery` opens. When i choose an image from the gallery it is shows it in an `ImageView` of my `Activity` but after choosing second time the following error occuring

```
01-13 17:55:25.323: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14899): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Here is the source code i am using:

```
public class MyImage extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Gallery gallery;
     private Uri[] mUrls;  
    String[] mFiles=null;  
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

          File images = Environment.getDataDirectory();  
                 File[] imagelist = images.listFiles();  

                  mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];  

                          for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++)  
                          {  
                              mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();  
                          }  
                          mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];  

                          for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++)  
                          {  
                              mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]);     
                          }     

                          Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);  
                          g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));  
                          g.setFadingEdgeLength(40);  
    }

     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{  

                 int mGalleryItemBackground;  
                 public ImageAdapter(Context c)  {     
                     mContext = c;     
                 }  
                 public int getCount(){  
                     return mUrls.length;  
                 }  
                 public Object getItem(int position){  
                     return position;  
                 }  
                 public long getItemId(int position) {  
                     return position;  
                 }  
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){  
                     ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);  

                     i.setImageURI(mUrls[position]);  
                     i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);  
                     i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(260, 210));  
                     return i;  
                 }     
                 private Context mContext;  
                 }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of answer related to this.
[Check it out](http://bit.ly/hyU3Cl).

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this exactly same problem too. What you can do to prevent this from happening is to make sure you recycle the previous Bitmap before loading the new one. Call Bitmap.recycle() to do this. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()

I don't see where you handle the Bitmaps in you code but you get the idea?

Another thing when handling Bitmaps is to keep in ming how big they actually are when read into memory and do you really need to have that large images for your usecase. You can read the Bitmap to your app with lower sample rate if you don't need to have the full image. This saves a lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

It is very common problem. It is maybe because you are having many images, and the Android emulator heap size is small. So you have to recycle your imagebitmap each time after use.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586685/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android).