# Error inflating class <unknown> which I know is a webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-inflate

I need help, I have an application published on the market using a webview to present information.. Every now and then i get error reports like this one:

http://pastebin.com/zQ16Sf2z

The error points to my inflation-line of my activity:

`setContentView(R.layout.view);`

`Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class <unknown>` must mean

`<WebView android:id="@+id/WebView" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></WebView>`

in my layout http://pastebin.com/MFAPawin

Please help me or give me a hint for a start in the right direction! This is a problem I have had for a long time and have not been able to solve..
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception that is thrown when creating your layout. So in short- use less Memory. But seriously when you run out of memory all kinds of things will fail.

Without seeing any of your code my suggestion is that you may have a memory leak somewhere. It's hard to tell with seeing any code but check out:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

for some tips that may help.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.. I have a pretty large project. Can you tell if the error is in the current layout or class? is there any tools for helping me find memory leaks?

Comment: The eclipse adt plugin has some memory analyzer tools.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your bitmap size exceeds VM budget (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError). You might look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/823966#823966) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586685/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android) for a solution.

Comment: I think that is funny, because I use no bitmaps.. Only very small drawables of about 5kb