# android - create gallery with photos from sdcard

Tags: android

I am trying to create gallery with photos from sdcard. I have a database table. One of the columns in the table has a path to a photo.

I am following this link as a guideline, but this sample code retrieves image ids from res/drawable directory. I am not sure how to modify it to make my code work.

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html

But as mentioned, I want to display photos with whatever images exist in the database table. The following code is ImageAdapter.

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;

    int imageBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.milestone_style);
        imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.milestone_style_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        ta.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imagePhotosLocations.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        if (milestones != null && !milestones.isEmpty()) {
            Milestone milestone = milestones.get(0);
            String imageFileLocation = milestone.getFileLocation();
            System.out.println("imageFileLocation="+imageFileLocation);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 26;
            Bitmap b;
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
            try {
                if (imageFileLocation.startsWith("content://")) {
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(imageFileLocation)), null, options);
                } else {
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFileLocation, options);
                }
                iv.setImageBitmap(b);
                iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
                // milestoneImageView.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return iv;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is one of the methods in activity.

```
private String[] imagePhotosLocations;

private void init() {
    milestones = getMilestones();
    imagePhotosLocations = new String[milestones.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for (Milestone milestone : milestones) {
        imagePhotosLocations[index++] = milestone.getFileLocation();
    }
}

private void initializeGallery() {
    milestoneImageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto);
    Gallery milestoneGallery = (Gallery) this.findViewById(R.id.milestoneGallery);
    if (milestoneGallery == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("milestoneGallery can not be null.");
    }
    milestoneGallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    milestoneGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int which, long arg3) {
            String imageFileLocation = imagePhotosLocations[which];
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 26;
            Bitmap b;
            try {
                if (imageFileLocation.startsWith("content://")) {
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(imageFileLocation)), null, options);
                } else {
                    b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFileLocation, options);
                }
                milestoneImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps which I used,

1. First check if the SD card is mounted.
2. Query your database.Details on this can be found here:
   [SQLite tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).
3. The Query returns a cursor for the result set.
4. Use a custom Cursor Adapter (Refer: [Custom Cursor Adapter](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/))
5. Some times if the image is too large ,loading the image into bitmap may exceed VM budget. So refer this article  [Avoiding out of memory issue while loading image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586685/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)
6. So the cursor adapter returns an image view as its done in your code.
7. finally bind this custom adapter to your gallary.

hope this answers your question.