# outofmemoryerror while making bitmap

Tags: android, camera, out-of-memory

I am making the camer application which can composite the camera preview and png.

I would like to save the images in onPictureTaken callback

my source is below

```
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            //preview from camera
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); 

            // overlay image 
            Bitmap overlayBmp = overlay.getDrawingCache(); 

            //blank beatmap 
            Bitmap blankBitmap = 
            Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), 
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

            //make canvas
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(blankBitmap); 

            //composite image
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null,new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 
    bitmap.getHeight()), null); 
            canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBmp, null,new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 
    bitmap.getHeight()), null);
```

However it shows outofmemoryerror,how can I solve this problem..?

```
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:585)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at com.example.firstcameraappli.MainActivity$2.onPictureTaken(MainActivity.java:103)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:750)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at      android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-20 15:13:49.114: E/AndroidRuntime(31647):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
```

Comment: It seems to be a memory leak. What's the size of the captured image

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this code....

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback()
{

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {

        BitmapFactory.Options opt;

        opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
        Parameters parameters = arg1.getParameters();
        Size size = parameters.getPictureSize();

        int height11 = size.height;
        int width11 = size.width;
        float mb = (width11 * height11) / 1024000;

        if (mb > 4f)
            opt.inSampleSize = 4;
        else if (mb > 3f)
            opt.inSampleSize = 2;

        //preview from camera
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,opt); 


    }
}
```

get image in bitmap then you use as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Sandip! inSampleSize is good hint for me,but I think problem does not happen only when 'BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray'. There are outofmemoryerror in canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null,new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 
     bitmap.getHeight()), null);  how can I resolve this?

Comment: I think drawBitmap() is your custom method.

Comment: createBitmap still shows outofmemoryerror  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Comment: When I use small number ((ex)100,100) instead of (v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height). it works.I can use opt for createBitmap method?

Comment: try this Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap , 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), null, true);

Comment: but you have already one bitmap with image then why you need to create another bitmap?

Comment: thanks again! it was my misunderstaning,v.getLayoutParams().width returns -1 .... .its not because of memoryerror.

Comment: you solved my problem, Thank you, I was decoding without "BitmapFactory.Options"

Comment: @naveed ahmed you  are welcome to get solution here. I put it because many persons suffering with this issue and they can get solution here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known issue on Android. The problem is that manipulating bitmaps requires more memory than is available in most devices. You can use certain tricks however. Some discussions and solutions to help you:

- [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object?lq=1)
- http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html
- [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)
- [OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586685/outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save image to sdcard, try like this

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            camera.startPreview();
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        "/mnt/sdcard/mypicture.png");
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

            }

        }
```